# Python3 code keeps getting the error "conn is not recognized"

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3


import random

a = input("what is your username?")

b = ("what is your password?")

c = random.randint(100000,999999)

database = sqlite3.connect("login_username.db")

x = conn.cursor()

x.execute("""Username text,
             Password text,
             Login id integer
             """)

conn.commit()

x.execute("INSERT INTO login_username VALUES (a, b ,c )")

conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your connection variable is wrong. The code should be like that:

```
import sqlite3

import random

a = input("what is your username?")

b = ("what is your password?")

c = random.randint(100000,999999)

database = sqlite3.connect("login_username.db")

x = database.cursor()

x.execute("""Username text, Password text, Login id integer """)

database.commit()

x.execute("INSERT INTO login_username VALUES (a, b ,c )")

database.commit()
```